# C# File.ReadAllText Encoding.Utf8

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, character

I try to read string from a HTML file.
Here is my code:

```
string result = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\invoice.html", Encoding.UTF8);
```

Since the character set of the html file is charset=windows124, the result value does not come as utf-8

The result value contains;

```
 �</span><br>BAH�EL�EVLER<span>
```

Comment: Are you using .net Framework 4.8 or earlier, or a later framework? If the former, you can use `Encoding.Default` instead of `Encoding.UTF8`. If the latter, it's slightly more fiddly.

Comment: Are you sure about the charset windows124 ?

Comment: And do you mean "Windows-1252" ?

Comment: Sorry windows-1252

Comment: Try  `File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\invoice.html", Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));`

Comment: @MatthewWatson .net framework 4.6.1

Comment: I tried but an error occurred

Comment: No data is available for encoding 1252. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.'

Comment: Are you sure that you're compiling against .net 4.6? Because that error should only occur for .net Core or later. In any case, try adding this before the other code: `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);` (This method is NOT availaible for .net 4.8 or earlier, so if it works for you, it proves that you're not compiling against 4.6.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the location specified under your profile, I assume you mean `windows-1254` (Turkish)?

Try:

```
Encoding turkishEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");
string result = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\invoice.html", turkishEncoding);
```

For reference, see the encodings-list under: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-6.0

Comment: `System.Text.EncodingProvider ppp = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);`

Comment: adding these codes solved my problem.Thank you